# How to remove deleted folder from remote repository in Git?

Tags: git

i deleted a folder from my local Git repository then i committed and pushed the changes to the remote repository, the files are deleted but the folder and the sub folder are still there. How could i remove the empty folder from the remote repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git doesn't actually store directories.  It just makes directories wherever it needs them to hold the files that are in the repository.  If a new clone still creates those directories, make sure you don't have files you can't see (like .gitignore) present.

Answer (score 21):

You can force git to quit tracking a local file by calling:

`git rm file.txt #warning, this also deletes the file from your filesystem`

You can delete an entire directory (and it's contents) by calling:

`git rm -rf directory`

Comment: after that the git-ignore will not track the new generated files from bin or gen folder. This is what I was searching for ... it is simpler than I thought