# Delete a folder in my local repo and my bitbucket repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working with a bibucket git and everything works very well.I have the main repo called php on bitbucket.I cloned the repo and inside the local repo,i created a folder called oop and inside it i created two folders namespaces,overloading.

The structure looks like this:

```
   php --- parent folder

   oop --- child folder

-namespaces ---- namespaces.php --- files inside the child folder oop
-overloading --- overloading.php --- files inside the child folder oop
```

I added everything i had to my local repo

```
git add .
```

and made my initial commit

```
git commit -m "my initial commit"
```

i pushed this to bit bucket

```
git push -u origin master
```

However,yesterday,i needed to rename my oop folder to oopnotes.I did rename successfully and started committing as usual.However on my bitbucket repo,instead of seeing the only oopnotes folder,i also see the old oop folder from back when i had not renamed.

Does it mean i still have the old oop folder in my local repo and how can i get rid of it on my local repo and my bitbucket repo?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `git rm` to remove old folder

Comment: I have tried that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074056/how-to-remove-deleted-folder-from-remote-repository-in-git but i have no clue what that does.Does it delete the folder old folder in my local repo and how will i delete the folder on bitbucket?.

Comment: it deletes file from your working directory and index, so then you just need to push removal onto server